# Too complicated to use a common table expression for this?

Tags: sql

Given that the following Common Table Expression generates all integers between two numbers (1 and 9 in this case):

```
WITH numbers(n) AS
(
  SELECT 1 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1 as n FROM numbers WHERE n < 9
)
select * from numbers
```

I have a table called Levels:

```
SELECT * from Levels

Player  StartingLevel   EndingLevel
john     2              4
Ed       7              8
```

I want a CTE to return a single row for each level of difficulty within the range for each player, e.g:

```
PLAYER CurrentLevel
John   2
John   3
John   4
Ed     7
Ed     8
```

can that be done with a CTE?  or do I just need to write a stored proc to do it?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
WITH playerlevels(player, level) AS
(
   SELECT player, startingLevel
   From Levels
   Union all 
   SELECT player, cast(p.level+1 as integer)
   from playerlevels p
     join Levels l 
         On p.player = l.player
   where p.level+1 <= l.EndingLevel
)
select * from playerlevels
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply join your CTE to your levels table using `BETWEEN`:

```
WITH numbers(n) AS
(
  SELECT 1 as n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n+1 as n 
  FROM numbers 
  WHERE n < 9
)
SELECT l.Player, n.n AS CurrentLevel
FROM numbers n
JOIN Levels l
  ON n.n BETWEEN l.StartingLevel AND l.EndingLevel
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72ef5/3/0)